# proof verification on stone weierstrass problem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

Let $f$ be a continuous function in $[a,b]$ stone-weierstrass theorem tell us that it exist a polynomial sequence {$p_n$} such that $p_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly in $[a,b]$. Suppose $m_n$ is the degree of the polynomial $p_n$ if $f$ a polynomial show that $m_n \rightarrow \infty$.

Proof:

let  $m_n \rightarrow k$ , $k \in \mathbb{N}$ consider also $p_n= a_0x^{b_0}+a_1x^{b_1}+...+a_nx^{b_n}$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$  , $b_i \in \mathbb{N}$, $0\leq i\leq n$ and

$b_i<b_{i+1} $ now since $m_n \rightarrow k \Rightarrow $  $lim p_n\rightarrow a_0x^{b_0}+a_1x^{b_1}+...+a_nx^{k}$ and $a_n \neq0 $ now since $p_n \rightarrow f$

$\left | a_0x^{b_0}+a_1x^{b_1}+...+a_nx^{k}-f \right |<\varepsilon ,\: \forall \varepsilon >0$ and this is a contradiction because $a_0x^{b_0}+a_1x^{b_1}+...+a_nx^{k} $ is a finite sum wich means i can find one $\varepsilon$  such that $\left| a_0x^{b_0}+a_1x^{b_1}+...+a_nx^{k}-f \right |> \varepsilon $.

I am sure this isn't right,  but is the idea correct ? Can someone help me prove it formally? Thanks.

PS Where can I find more problems on the  stone-weierstrass theorem?

Comment: Please rewrite "Suppose $m_n$ is the degree of the polynomial $p_n$ if $f$ a polynomial show that $m_n \rightarrow \infty$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is not a polynomial. Here is a proof using that every norm on a finite dimensional normed space is equivalent.

Assume that we can find a subsequence of the $m_n$ such that $m_n\leq N$ where $\deg p_n = m_n$ and $\sup_{x\in [a,b]}|p_n(x)-f(x)|\rightarrow 0$. We let $p_n$ and $m_n$ denote the subsequence so we assume that $m_n\leq N$ for all $n$.

Clearly the sequence $\sup_{x\in [a,b]}|p_n(x)|$ is bounded. An alternative norm on the polynomials of degree at most $N$ is given by
$$\|\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_kx^k\|_{\mathrm{new}} = \sum_{k=1}^{N}|a_k|.$$

This implies that the sequence of coefficients are bounded. By repeated use of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem (applied $N$ times) we can pick out a subsequence $p_{n_k}$ such that the coefficients of the polynomial converge so that $p_{n_k}$ converges to a polynomial $p$ of degree at most $N$. This implies that $\sup_{x\in [a,b]}|p(x)-f(x)| = 0$ which is a contradiction since $f$ was not a polynomial.